# WPF ResizeMode Changes Window Size

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

I am currently making a wpf application and want to disable window resizing during certain operations. I have been using `this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanMinimize;`, which does exactly what I want, but it makes the window larger than before.

I don't know if it's possible, but is there a way to avoid the enlarging of the window?

EDIT:

Here's a very simple wpf application that demonstrates this problem.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Trigger CanMinimize" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,248,0,0" Name="canMin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Click="canMin_Click" />
        <Button Content="Trigger CanResize" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="327,248,0,0" Name="canRes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Click="canRes_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs file:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void canMin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
        }

        private void canRes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your working?

Comment: @Veleous Updated with example

Comment: I didn;t understand what do you mean by "it makes the window larger than before", because once you set the ResizeMode to canMinimize there is no way to resize the window. Could you please share your code, similar type of example

Comment: The code works as intended for me on .NET 4.5...

Comment: @Shoe the size of the window doesn't change at all when switching between resize modes? I am currently using .NET 4.0, for the record.

Comment: @mastur No the only visible change I see is the maximize button. The window size stays the same. I am on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: I can confirm this mysterious size change when using the question author's code example on Windows 7 64 bit and .NET 4.0.

Comment: @sheridan Weird, I just tried it at 4.0 on 7 64 bit and it works

Comment: That is weird @shoe... I tried it both with and without setting the `Width` and `Height` on the `Window` and it happened on both occasions. I also did a search online and found other people complaining about this problem, but apparently without any solutions.

Comment: It appears that this is a bug, and that it works on .NET 4.5. Is an upgrade to 4.5 a possibility for you?

Answer (score 0):

Actualy I don't really understand what "makes window larger" means, but alternatively you can set

```
MaxWidth = ActualWidth;
MinWidth = ActualWidth;
MaxHeight = ActualHeight;
MinHeight = ActualHeight;
```

instead of

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResize;
```

In case you want to re-enable resize set those properties to `double.NaN`.

.

Answer (score 0):

To disallow resizing simply do the following:

`ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;`

It will also remove the minimize and maximize buttons.